# How to get previous value?

Tags: influxdb, flux, flux-influxdb

I have pretty simple function to apply to inputStream and get outputStream. I was very positive I could accomplish this using flux language, but it turns out getting the previous value in the stream might be a showstopper. Here is the function pseudo-code:

```
step = some constant value
for(pos = 0; pos < totalPoints, pos++)
{
    if (pos == 0)
        outputStream[pos] = step * (0.5 * inputStream[pos])
    else if (pos == totalPoints - 1)
        outputStream[pos] = outputStream[pos - 1] + (step * (0.5 * inputStream[pos]))
    else
        outputStream[pos] = outputStream[pos - 1] + (step * inputStream[pos])
}
```

Using the map could have been one option, but how to

1. get `outputStream[pos - 1]`? Can I save `outputStream[pos]` into some temporary variable and then use it?
2. how to detect first and last points of the stream?